# Laravel: strange behavior when I try to serve ajax and non-ajax request on same route (Caching)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I registered a `GET` route for `laravel.dev/test`. The corresponding controller for the route would distinguish whether the request is ajax or not.

When I type `laravel.dev/test` on the browser, Laravel detect that it's not an ajax request and uses `return View::make()` to generate the page. Then `Backbone.js` code on the page make an ajax request to `laravel.dev/test` and Laravel uses `return Response::json` to return a JSON.

It's all fine until when I try to navigate away from the page and then use the browser button to navigate back to `laravel.dev/test` that it print out the json as the response, which is not what I expect since I'm not making an ajax request.

Comment: I guess you didn't first make the ajax request, then the 'normal' request and after that clicked the back button? 
How do you detect the diff between the normal and ajax request? And to debug, print out the sent headers on the unexpected ajax response :)

Comment: `Request::ajax()` can be used to test ajax request. The unexpected header: `Request URL:http://laravel.dev/test
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)`

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue. Use your browser's dev tools to see if a request was really made and got json as a response, or if it was fetched from the cache. EDIT: Well now we know it's a cache issue.

Comment: @Alex-Info.net I captured a photo of the chrome dev tools: http://i.imgur.com/N7uBb3v.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a caching issue. Just to try and get some results, add this to your controller (ajax and non-ajax) to force-disable caching:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

And see if chrome still fetches from the cache on the back button.

Comment: I tried to place your code before I return `View::make`, and I also tried `$response = Response::make(View::make());` then `$respose->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate')` for both ajax and non-ajax but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It is normal behavior for browser to load pages from cache on back-button, you are fighting what is probably a losing battle. One final try : `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store");` (from http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/). Otherwise you should really use different routes for ajax and non-ajax.

Comment: It kinda works in that back button no longer return JSON. But Backbone.js functionality is completely broken. For the sake of avoiding debugging my Backbone codes I guess I would use the different route approach for good.

Comment: Just because I'm really curious, how/why is backbone "completely broken" by this header ? What reault are you getting ? Also, glad you are heading the different routes way, much cleaner.

Comment: My backbone.js code at initialization would `fetch()` a json from the server to populate a collection which is then passed to a collection view and then render some html tag on the page. Previously before I added cache-control it was 'semi-broken' in that I have to refresh a few times for it to render something on the page (sometime it just display a blank page).

Comment: However after adding cache-control it is 'completely-broken' in that my page is blank no matter how many time I refresh it. When I look at the chrome dev tool, it did make a ajax get request (judging by the header X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest) and the response is indeed a json as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a laravel or backbone, but a [chrome issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108766)! [Check this out too](http://sdqali.in/blog/2012/11/27/on-rest-content-type-google-chrome-and-caching/).

The solution that worked for me is to put

```
return Response::json($this->data)->header("Vary", "Accept");
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is in Laravel 5.1, but the principle should work for all previous versions as well.

The way I handled it was with two routes pointing to the same method, but with one ending in a `.json` extension:

```
get('items', ['as' => 'items', 'uses' => 'ItemsController@index']);
get('items.json', ['as' => 'items', 'uses' => 'ItemsController@index']);
```

Then inside my `index()` method:

```
$data = []; // your collection

if ($this->request->ajax()) {
    return response()->json($data); // replace with actual JSON data
}

return view('items.index', compact('data'));
```

This allows for a dedicated URL for JSON responses, uses the same method and data, and never interferes with my back button.